# Why do Haskell list ranges give an empty list when reversed?

Tags: haskell

Why does Haskell read backwards list ranges as empty lists?
It there some reason for this or is it just that it can't parse them backwards?

Example from GHCi:

```
>[1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
>[5..1]
[]
```

I'd expect [5,4,3,2,1], for what I'd say are obvious reasons, but you just get an empty list.

Comment: Try `[5, 4..1]`

Comment: If you write it as `[x .. y]`, it will take the successor of `x` each time until (and including) `y`. You can use `[x0, x1 .. y]`, then it will use the delta between `x1` and `x0` as *step* value.

Comment: You start at 5 and count up until you reach 1. How many numbers do you get?

Comment: Thanks guys, I get it.